# Google Distance Matrix API - train distance

Tags: java, google-maps

I'm using the Google Distance Matrix API with Java. I want to calculate the train-distance between two cities. One of the cities has no train station. The problem is, google doesn't just calculate the train-distance. It always adds the car-distance from the city without trainstation to the next city with a train station. But for my project i just need the train-distance.

This is a part of my code:

```
DistanceMatrix matrix = DistanceMatrixApi.newRequest(context)
        .origins(origins)
        .destinations(destinations)
        .mode(TravelMode.TRANSIT)
        .transitModes(TransitMode.TRAIN)
        .units(Unit.METRIC)
        .await();
```

In the documentation I can't find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps search algorithms were designed to solve real-world transportation routes, which means that sending a train to a location where the passenger cannot get off is not feasible and therefore not reflected in the routes. I cannot think of any way to extract that information from Google Maps, except possibly doing a direct Directions query, though I doubt it would have different results, since it uses (as far as I can tell) the fundamentally same algorithm for all of its services.

Using a database such as OpenStreetMap (using free, limitless APIs like [Overpass](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to access via HTTP in Java) is probably the best solution. If you want a quick fix, and you are capable of identifying cities without train stations, taking the linear distance between the two cities probably returns a reasonable (though deflated) estimate using the [Geometry Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?hl=en#SphericalGeometry).

Sorry there is not a solution I can see, but this is the best I have.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! But I think i didn't explain it well enough. When I send a request from point A (city with train station) to point B (city without train station), google always combines the train distance from point A to the nearest city of point B with a train station. From this nearest city of point B google calculates the car-distance to point B (which isn't reachable by train). As a result I get the summary of the car-distance and the train-distance. But for my project I just need the train-distance from point A to the nearest city of point B where a train station is existing.

Comment: That was the situation I was envisioning. How can my answer be improved or answer my question? I don't think Google Maps can do it; OpenStreetMap is the first thing that comes to mind for getting data on railroads, it will be _extremely_ difficult to craft a query.